# Preferred way to deliver UWP app without Windows Store

Tags: windows, uwp, sideloading, appv

I need to deliver an UWP app (*) that the client will install on tablets inside their network. The Windows Store is blocked by policy.

There is a procedure for signing and sideloading an **.appx** package (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/micham/2014/05/30/sideloading-store-apps-to-windows-8-1-devices/) but it's very complicated.

Is there a way to bundle the app as an **.msi** or **.exe** (or APP-V package) instead?

(*) It must be an UWP app to register as a File Open Picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or have the organization/client signup for a Windows Enterprise store. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/business-store

Answer (score 7):

Yes of course it is possible to create an installer for your app, in Visual Studio go to "Project\Store\Create App Packages..." menu and when it will ask you if you want to upload the packages to Windows Store simply click No.

This will generate the app packages plus an easy to run powershell script that when run will install the app (or upgrade to a new version if there was a previous one already installed)

Comment: does this allows developers to deploy apps to end users? I was under the impression unlike .msi or .exe, an end user would have to enable something like "side-loading" or "developer mode". Has this finally changed?

Comment: We can't do that as if the Windows Store itself is blocked by the policy, it makes sense to also block Developer or Sideload apps options. Is there a way for the admins to allow this app only without changing the option globally?